# Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'Router'. Did you mean 'navigated'?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have no idea why, but it was suddenly stopped working... The `import` is correct but it cannot see `navigate()` method.. any ideas? 
Every answer for this is about missing `import` but there is a correct `import` here. `navigate()` stopped working in every part of my code LOL it is only example here. Any ideas?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as  AuthActions from './auth.actions'
import * as UserDetailsActions from '../user/user-store/user.actions';
import * as StudentActions from '../../student/student-store/student.actions';

import { map, mergeMap, switchMap, switchMapTo, concatMapTo, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions,
                private router: Router) { }

    @Effect()
    authSignin = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN),
            map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
                return action.payload;
            }),
            switchMap((authData: any) => {

                //here should be request to backend server with JWT
                //set token and and username or user id
                const userRetunedFromRequest = {
                    id: '5',
                    username: authData.username,
                    role: authData.role
                }

                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(userRetunedFromRequest));
                //----------------------------------------------------

                return [
                    new AuthActions.SigninUser,
                    new UserDetailsActions.GetUserDetailsById
                ]
            })
        );

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    loginRedirect = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(AuthActions.SIGNIN_USER),
            map((action: AuthActions.SigninUser) => {
                let url = this.navigateByUserRole();
                this.router.navigate([`/${url}`]);
            })
        );


    private navigateByUserRole(): string {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).role === 'PARENT' ? 'student' : 'teacher';
    }

}
```

Comment: console log the URL. there might be an issue that url is not available.

Comment: Console log the `this.router` too. It seems it may have been overriden somehow in the dependency injection or sth.

Comment: Any chances of context change of `this` .. try logging and check.

Comment: what does it mean and how could it be overriden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Typescript issue. Logging as suggested in the comments won't help here because the problem is at compilation time.

Try `` (<any>this.router).navigate([`/${url}`]); `` and if that fixes your problem, then you probably have an issue with your dependencies versions. Create a new project from scratch and use the generated `package.json` to update your project's one.

Comment: <any> worked here. What helped was just removing node_modules. Strange, anyway thank you!

Comment: this worked for me too but it refreshes the entire website its

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be raised because of your imports with "@angular/router" like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: it worked for me. router imported from express router so it happens. great.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when the typescript automatically adds the "import {} from ''" it uses different modules. Let me explain with an example:

I wrote the following to add dependency.

```
    constructor(private router: Router){}
```

The typescript added:

```
    import {Router} from "express"
```

instead of:

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router'
```

So the compiler gave me the same error that you faced and rightly so. I change the first import statement to the second one and the error was resolved. Keep an eye on these automatic imports to verify.